# Asking user input until a valid datetime is given (bloated try-except blocks)

Tags: python, datetime, validation, error-handling

Originally asked this on SO but was redirected here.

I have a script that's asking the user to input a lot of dates, mostly in functions similar to the one below. These need to account for invalid date formats:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import datetime as dtt

def week_init():
        """Creates an initial week datetime and determines what the checking cutoff
        'beforeday' to be used in Stage 2 is."""
        week = input('Week to check: MM/DD/YYYY\n')
        switch = 1
        while switch == 1:
            try:
                week = dtt.datetime.strptime(week,'%m/%d/%Y') #turns input to a datetime
                switch = 0
            except ValueError: #couldn't parse as a date MM/DD/YYYY
                week = input('Unrecognized date format, please try again: MM/DD/YYYY\n')
        beforeday = (input('Check days before date (Press enter to use today): MM/DD/YYYY\n')
            or dtt.date.today())
        if (beforeday != dtt.date.today()):
            switch = 1
            while switch == 1:
                try:
                    beforeday = dtt.datetime.strptime(beforeday,'%m/%d/%Y')
                    switch = 0
                except ValueError: #couldn't parse as a date MM/DD/YYYY
                    beforeday = input('Unrecognized date format, please try again: MM/DD/YYYY\n')
        return week, beforeday
```

There are also functions that check an index for a given date, and have to deal with a given date not matching any of the indices:

```
def spotmap(week, bam, pt):
    """Maps the pivoted data for the chosen week to the BAM dataframe's SD column."""
    print('Mapping data to BAM... ',end=''),
    switch = 1
    while switch == 1:
        try:
            bam['SD'] = bam.index.to_series().map(pt.fillna(0)['len',week])
            switch = 0
        except KeyError: #date doesn't match any of the pivot table's columns
            print('Invalid date, please try again.')
            week = input('Week start date (Sunday): MM/DD/YYYY\n')
    print('Done')
    return bam
```

As the script has a lot of things to do after it gets these dates, I don't want it to crash when it has a problem, but it can't proceed without correct date inputs so I currently have it looping with those "switch" variables controlling when it is willing to move on with a valid date. As you can see, though, these try/except blocks are rapidly bloating the otherwise straightforward code. Is there a way to condense these things? Also, a better method than the switches?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386592/repetitive-try-and-except-clauses

The answers here suggested decorators, but as far as I can tell from the documentation and pages like [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/), those are for wrapping functions, not for replacing interior code blocks. Also I'm not sure how useful they'd be, because the try/except blocks are mostly unique in what they're trying to accomplish (ie, which variable they're changing or whether they're checking against an index). I guess I'm really just hoping for some better general exception-handling syntax.

Comment: Note that `while true:` with `break` is much more pythonic than setting a flag like `switch`. Also see the canonical https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761

Comment: As far as I can see, you're not using `numpy`, `pandas` and `xlwings` in the code snippet, so you could omit them.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will focus on the main question, i.e. how to decompose the code so that checks are kept, but the code does not get bloated with them.

Regarding the first part: I recommend to factor out the code asking for input, and split the initialization function into two separate ones. Something like this:

```
import datetime as dtt

def read_date(prompt, def_date=None):
          switch = 1
          while switch == 1:
                week = input(prompt) or def_date
                try:
                       week = dtt.datetime.strptime(week,'%m/%d/%Y')
                       switch = 0
                except ValueError:
                       print('Unrecognized date format, please try again\n')
          return week

def init_week():
    return read_date('Week to check: MM/DD/YYYY\n')

def init_before_day():
    return read_date('Check days before date (Press enter to use today): MM/DD/YYYY\n', '{0:%m/%d/%Y}'.format(dtt.date.today()))

def week_init():
    return [init_week(), init_before_day()]
    # alternatively (without the helpers): return [read_date(), read_date(dtt.date.today())]
```

For the second part, I suggest factoring out the mapping logic from inputting the date (or at least, the date should also be read in the function itself -- but receiving it as a parameter, and then reading it again is very messy IMHO). So this would look something like the following:

```
def spotmap_impl(week, bam, pt):
    bam['SD'] = bam.index.to_series().map(pt.fillna(0)['len',week])
    return bam

def spotmap(bam, pt):
    switch = 1
    while switch == 1:
        try:
            week = input('Week start date (Sunday): MM/DD/YYYY\n')
            bam = spotmap_impl(week, bam, pt)
            switch = 0
        except KeyError:
            print('Invalid date, please try again.')
    return bam;
```

Remarks:

- I tried to leave the original names as much as possible, but I feel they could be improved (e.g. in `read_date` we are reading a date, which is then somehow used as a week; so I would call the internal variable something like `input_date`. Also instead of `switch`, I would use a name like `success`, and values `True`/`False`, instead of `1` and `0`).
- I could not test the second part, as I do not understand exactly what is the meaning and contents of `bam` and `pt`, but I hope you get the idea :) (Btw., these variable names might be improved too.)
- You might want to add further validation code to the parameters of `spotmap_impl`. And then write unit tests for it, if you haven't done so yet ;)

Comment: Thanks; I've applied this function encapsulation to the functions and appended it to the original question.